# Aloha editor - contenthadler settings per editable not making any changes

Tags: rich-text-editor, sanitize, aloha-editor

I have multiple (6) editables with two different classes (.html_edit_simple, .html_edit_advanced) on website and I want to divide them by class and each to have its own contentHandler settings.

But no matter what I try, only the default settings are loaded.

The ones defined under `window.Aloha.settings.contentHandler.handler.sanitize` don't apply at all.

The settings code that I use is the following:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    if (window.Aloha === undefined || window.Aloha === null) {
        window.Aloha = {};
    }

    window.Aloha.settings = { sidebar: { disabled: true } };
    window.Aloha.settings.contentHandler = {
        insertHtml: [ 'word', 'generic', 'oembed', 'sanitize' ],
        initEditable: [ 'sanitize' ],
        getContents: [ 'blockelement', 'sanitize', 'basic' ],
        sanitize: 'relaxed', // relaxed, restricted, basic,
        allows: {
            elements: ['strong', 'em', 'i', 'b', 'blockquote', 'br', 'cite', 'code', 'dd', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 'q', 'small', 'strike', 'sub', 'sup', 'u', 'ul', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'img', 'video', 'audio']
        },
        handler: {
            generic: {
                transformFormattings: false
            },
            sanitize: {
                '.html_edit_simple': { elements: [ 'b', 'i', 'strong', 'em', 'strike', 'u', 'a' ] },
                '.html_edit_advanced': { elements: [ 'b', 'i', 'strong', 'em', 'strike', 'u', 'a', 'br', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'sub', 'sup', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'div', 'img', 'video', 'audio' ] }
            }
        }
    }
})(window);
```

I made a console log just before Aloha.ready and everything is loaded correctly.
So where could be the issue.

Comment: Anybody?
These settings were made following the aloha editor contenthandler documentation and they should work.

Comment: forgot to post the link... here it is  http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_contenthandler.html

Comment: I also followed the documentation. For me, the inclusion of the right plugins helped. In addition to the contenthandler the paste plugin was also necessary.
Then also the sanatizen the specified editables worked.